# How to querying and aggregate multiple collection in Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I need to retrieve a monthly work orders collection by project and list of users (in the month I could have some project's OdL hours not included in the users list and the users could have some OdL of other projects).
The OdL model contains the strings for project (projectCode) and user (userId).
I send to the service the dates in Timestamp format, the code of the project and an array with users list.

```
this.loadGantt(from: Timestamp, to: Timestamp, projectCode: string, users: string[]){...}
```

I tried to execute single queries, one for project code and one for single user.
These are the queries of the service:

```
this.docs = this.afs.collection<OdlModel>('odl', ref => {
      return ref.where('projectCode', '==', project)
        .where('date', '>=', from)
        .where('date', '<=', to)
        .orderBy('date', 'asc');
    })
      .snapshotChanges().pipe(map(coll => {
        return coll.map(doc => ({ id: doc.payload.doc.id, ...doc.payload.doc.data()}));
      }));
    return this.docs;

this.docs = this.afs.collection<OdlModel>('odl', ref => {
      return ref.where('userId', '==', user)
        .where('date', '>=', from)
        .where('date', '<=', to)
        .orderBy('date', 'asc');
    })
      .snapshotChanges().pipe(map(coll => {
        return coll.map(doc => ({ id: doc.payload.doc.id, ...doc.payload.doc.data()}));
      }));
    return this.docs;
```

This is the solution that I found:

```
loadGantt() {
    const momentDate: Moment = moment(new Date());
    this.firstDay = momentDate.startOf('month').toDate();
    this.lastDay = momentDate.endOf('month').toDate();
    const from = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(this.firstDay);
    const to = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(this.lastDay);
    this.odl = [];
    const odlArray = [];
    const a$ = this.odlService.getProjectOdlCollection(from, to, 'IGNC0954-IMI-19');
    odlArray.push(a$);
    this.user.forEach(u => {
      const b$ =  this.odlService.getUserOdlCollection(from, to, u);
      odlArray.push(b$);
    });
    const result$ = combineLatest([odlArray]);

    result$.subscribe(res => {
      res.map(r => {
         r.subscribe(odl => {
           odl.forEach(o => {
             const index = this.odl.findIndex(x => x.id === o.id);
             if (index === -1) {
               this.odl.push(o);
             }
           });
         });
      });
    });
  }
```

How to I get all data in a single Observable object?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a snippet which shows how to combine two or more Firestore collections from AngularFire into a single Observable object.

[Link here](https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/combine-firestore-collections-into-a-single-array-observable/)

**Data Structure**

```
const usersRef = this.afs.collection('users');

const fooPosts = usersRef.doc('userFoo').collection('posts').valueChanges();
const barPosts = usersRef.doc('userBar').collection('posts').valueChanges();
```

**Solution**

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';


const combinedList = combineLatest<any[]>(fooPosts, barPosts).pipe(
      map(arr => arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur) ) ),
      )
```

Also [this example](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-joins-similar-to-sql/) may also help with your issue.

Let me know if this was helpful.